# コラムの値を空白文字で区切り、別のコラムに分割したい

Tags: python, pandas

Pandasで以下のようなCSVファイルをDFとして読み込みました。
このDF内の、郵便番号と住所を別のコラムにしたいです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

下記のコードを試しました。

```
gyoumu_add_csv['split'] = gyoumu_add_csv['A'].str.split(' ')
gyoumu_add_csv['A1'] = gyoumu_add_csv['split'].str.get(0)
gyoumu_add_csv['A2'] = gyoumu_add_csv['split'].str.get(1)
```

しかし、以下のようなエラーが出ます。

```
C:\Users\ichir\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:1: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

どうすれば住所を分けることができるのでしょうか？
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

[pandas.Series.str.split](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) には次のように記されています

```
Notes
The handling of the n keyword depends on the number of found splits:
+   If found splits > n, make first n splits only
+   If found splits <= n, make all splits
+   If for a certain row the number of found splits < n, append None for padding up to n if expand=True

If using expand=True, Series and Index callers return DataFrame and MultiIndex objects, respectively.
Use of regex=False with a pat as a compiled regex will raise an error.
```

```py
df[['A1', 'A2']] = df['A'].str.split(' ', n=1, expand=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
import pandas as pd
import io

csv_data = '''
A
〒196-0022 東京都昭島市中神町1-23-20
〒190-0142 東京都あきる野市伊奈446-3
〒111-0025 東京都台東区東浅草2-21-5
〒124-0001 東京都葛飾区小菅4-21-11 エレガンス綾瀬5
〒143-0024 東京都大田区中央6-28-5
'''
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(csv_data))

# extract and join
df = df.join(df['A'].str.extract(r'(?P<A1>〒\d{3}-\d{4})\s+(?P<A2>.*)'))

print(df.to_markdown(index=False))
```

| A | A1 | A2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 〒196-0022 東京都昭島市中神町1-23-20 | 〒196-0022 | 東京都昭島市中神町1-23-20 |
| 〒190-0142 東京都あきる野市伊奈446-3 | 〒190-0142 | 東京都あきる野市伊奈446-3 |
| 〒111-0025 東京都台東区東浅草2-21-5 | 〒111-0025 | 東京都台東区東浅草2-21-5 |
| 〒124-0001 東京都葛飾区小菅4-21-11 エレガンス綾瀬5 | 〒124-0001 | 東京都葛飾区小菅4-21-11 エレガンス綾瀬5 |
| 〒143-0024 東京都大田区中央6-28-5 | 〒143-0024 | 東京都大田区中央6-28-5 |